# How to set an *integer* size of markers in plotly scatter_3d (not Scatter3d)?

Tags: plotly

Calling like `px.scatter_3d(..., size=1)` results in the following error which seems like a bug:

```
Value of 'size' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'
```

Note I am not talking about Scatter3d which is a separate function with slightly different API.

I am using this in python but the API should be common across languages.

Comment: it's not a bug,  but difference in API specification.  *size* in px is typically a column in dataframe.  if you specifically wanna set size as you do with go `px.scatter_3d().update_traces(marker_size=1)`

Comment: @RobRaymond Yes! that works. It feels like the docs here (https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter_3d.html) indicate the other way should work. Maybe I am reading them wrong.

Comment: it does say str or int,  a column name in a dataframe can be an int ...